# Get all users permissions from all groups in JFrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I want to get all groups in JFrog Artifactory and members part of that group and their permissions.

I have tried below REST API (api/security/users and api/security/groups) to get details but could not get all the details.

```
curl -u admin:password http://localhost/artifactory/api/security/users > artifactuser.txt
grep uri artifactuser.txt | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/,/ /g'  | sed 's/"//g' > userslist
for i in  `cat userslist`; do curl -u admin:password $i;echo "========================================="; done
```

I need to get all groups and members and their permissions.

Answer (score 1):

There seems no api to get a list of users and the groups directly so you might need to follow the below steps:

1. Get list of all users using `/api/security/users`
2. Once you have list of all the users you can use another api `/api/security/users/<username>` to get detailed info for a user. This includes group name the privileges.

Also since the response is in JSON I will suggest you to use jq with shell/bash so that execution would be easy.

Hope so this helps.